# Using GCC's link-time optimization with static linked libraries

Tags: gcc, cmake, lto

I'm trying to use link-time optimizations with the `-flto` flag of GCC (6.1.1).

While it works fine with my code, it doesn't link with a static linked library I'm also building and linking with my project (which is [Engine](https://github.com/cpcdoy/Engine) and the library is [glsl-optimizer](https://github.com/aras-p/glsl-optimizer), just for reference).

Here is the output:

```
...
/usr/bin/ranlib: ir_expression_flattening.cpp.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
/usr/bin/ranlib: opt_function_inlining.cpp.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
/usr/bin/ranlib: opt_copy_propagation_elements.cpp.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
...
```

And after that, of course, I get several "undefined references" to some functions.

I did some research and found out that it might be because of `ar`, and I should try to use `gcc-ar`, but I'm not sure how I might do that.

Also, I'm using CMake that does not support lto (except on Intel's compiler on some platforms, so I read...). Even though, I tried using:

```
set_property(TARGET glsl_optimizer PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION True)
```

Which didn't work.

Also, I tried GCC's `-fuse-linker-plugin` flag which didn't work.

I guess I'll have to do it manually the old way directly using `gcc-ar`, or maybe there's some other method?

Comment: Did you try to replace `ar` with `gcc-ar` in `CMAKE_AR` cached variable in `CMakeCache.txt` or via CMake's GUI (under advanced options)? That `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` is not working for GCC is an [open issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15939) at CMake's GitLab page.

Comment: @Florian: I just tried and only setting `CMAKE_AR` doesn't solve the problem. You also need `CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE` and `CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH` (cf. @Mike Kinghan's answer)

Comment: [This quick fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461766) worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) CMake project that reproduces the problem:

```
$ ls -R hellow
hellow:
CMakeLists.txt  hello.c  libhello.c

$ cat hellow/CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (hellow)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -flto")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -flto")
#SET(CMAKE_AR  "gcc-ar")
#SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcs <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
#SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH   true)
add_library(hello STATIC libhello.c) 
add_executable(hellow hello.c)
target_link_libraries(hellow hello)
add_dependencies(hellow hello)


$ cat hellow/hello.c 
extern void hello(void);

int main(void)
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}

$ cat hellow/libhello.c 
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello");
}
```

Configuration is good:

```
$ mkdir build_hellow
$ cd build_hellow/
$ cmake ../hellow
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/dev/so/build_hellow
```

Build fails as per problem:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/libhello.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C static library libhello.a
/usr/bin/ar: CMakeFiles/hello.dir/libhello.c.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
/usr/bin/ranlib: libhello.c.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
[ 50%] Built target hello
Scanning dependencies of target hellow
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hellow.dir/hello.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable hellow
/tmp/ccV0lG36.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/hellow.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'hellow' failed
make[2]: *** [hellow] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/hellow.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hellow.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

There is more than one solution. One is to uncomment the 3 commented lines
in `CMakeLists.txt` above. Then:

```
$ cmake ../hellow/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/dev/so/build_hellow

$ make
Scanning dependencies of target hello
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/libhello.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C static library libhello.a
[ 50%] Built target hello
Scanning dependencies of target hellow
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hellow.dir/hello.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable hellow
[100%] Built target hellow

$ ./hellow 
Hello
```

This fix makes use of the following facts.

The build-breaking problem:

```
/usr/bin/ar: CMakeFiles/hello.dir/libhello.c.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
...
/usr/bin/ranlib: libhello.c.o: plugin needed to handle lto object
```

can solved by giving `ar` and `ranlib` the option:

```
--plugin=$(gcc --print-file-name=liblto_plugin.so)
```

However, GNU `ranlib` is merely a synonym for `ar -s`, and `gcc-ar` is a
wrapper for `ar` that supplies that plugin.

CMake's build template for a C static library is:

```
CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE ( = <CMAKE_AR> qc <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>)
CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH ( = <CMAKE_RANLIB> <TARGET>)
```

which for GNU `ar` is equivalent to:

```
CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE ( = <CMAKE_AR> qcs <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>)
CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH ( = true) # Or any other no-op command
```

So with these settings plus:

```
SET(CMAKE_AR  "gcc-ar")
```

we're good.

For a C++ project, of course, set `CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE` and `CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_FINISH`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly. You get the tick :)

Comment: I tried these steps with GCC5.4, while it "compiles with LTO" you don't see any of the optimisations take place that you would expect.

Comment: @BlamKiwi In [this archived message](https://lists.launchpad.net/kicad-developers/msg17690.html), the modify `CMAKE_AR`, `CMAKE_NM`, and `CMAKE_RANLIB`. Is this may be the reason? If that is the case, can somebody update the answer (my technical kwowledge is not enough to comprehand and explain it properly).

Comment: @HalilŞEN I never really quite managed to figure out whats going on. Although I noticed that Clang respects always_inline when LTOing

Comment: @Mike Kingham Can you elaborate on what exactly `liblto_plugin.so` does and what is the difference between your solution and using `-ffat-lto-objects` which also works? I asked another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934111/which-is-the-correct-way-to-build-a-static-library-with-link-time-code-generatio/) for this questions.

Comment: @bobeff `liblto_plugin.so` is the shared library plugin that supported LTO
for tools that are concerned with it. I hadn't heard of `-ffat-lto-objects` till now. It was introduced in
GCC 7, which had not been released when I wrote my answer. Its
documentation is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Comment: `SET(CMAKE_AR  "gcc-ar")` helped - thank you! Can you move it to the top?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to cross compile for armr5. Changing `"ar"` to `"gcc-ar"` helped.

Comment: Changing `CMAKE_AR` inside the cache doesn't seem to do anything (with Ninja generator), changing the variable inside CMakeLists has an effect, however. Any idea why this is?

Comment: The solution with `CMAKE_AR` having the "ar" replaced with "gcc-ar" fixes the problem, but ICEs on GCC 8.2 and some other search results also show similar problems with LTO with GCC 8.0, 8.1 and earlier versions.

Comment: The LTO crash happens only when a non-LTO code is linked with LTO code. Having everything or none compiled with LTO does not crash.

Comment: In other words, here is an answer that is 5 pages long.... good luck!!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue after porting to g++-11. It was probably caused by a change of defaults - using "slim" objects instead of "fat" - and adding `-ffat-lto-objects` option to CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS will solve it.

`-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-ffat-lto-objects"`

`-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-ffat-lto-objects"`

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326368/2289509) and also this [github issue](https://github.com/novacoin-project/novacoin/issues/393#issuecomment-1185480367).