# MinGW GCC: multiple definition of destructor and non-virtual thunk

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build elements library after few recent changes and can not make it link.

My toolchain:

- GCC 9.2.1 with MCF threads
- CMake 3.16.4

The commit that breaks the build: https://github.com/cycfi/elements/commit/104cef3cc19bf6f568b233a29679135a2c1f06ca

Relevant issue: https://github.com/cycfi/elements/issues/69

compiler flags: `-DNOMINMAX -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_UNICODE @CMakeFiles/Buttons.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -O3 -DNDEBUG -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects   -std=gnu++17`

error message:

```
[ 68%] Linking CXX executable Buttons.exe
cd /d D:\Files\C++\workspace_windows\elements_fork\build_fork\examples\buttons && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir/objects.a
C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc-ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -O3 -DNDEBUG -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects  -mwindows -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o Buttons.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libButtons.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\Buttons.dir\linklibs.rsp
C:/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: radio_button.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn208_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `cycfi::elements::basic_radio_button::~basic_radio_button()'; main.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn24_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: radio_button.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn208_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `non-virtual thunk to cycfi::elements::basic_radio_button::~basic_radio_button()'; main.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn24_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): first defined here
C:/mingw64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: radio_button.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn208_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): multiple definition of `non-virtual thunk to cycfi::elements::basic_radio_button::~basic_radio_button()'; main.cpp.obj (symbol from plugin):(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev[_ZThn24_N5cycfi8elements18basic_radio_buttonD1Ev]+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Current observations:

- This is not an ODR violation problem.
- There is no diamond inheritance in the project.
- https://github.com/Xeverous/elements/tree/radio-button-build-debug builds but https://github.com/Xeverous/elements/tree/radio-button-build-debug-1 does not - the only difference is that for the `-1` branch I added `radio_button` objects to the example
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39256013/4818802 does not help (added the 3 commented lines for C++) - I have a reverse problem, I'm getting multiple definitions instead of a missing definition
- I tried the example code in attachment from https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47218 but it does not reproduce the problem
- The problem does not occur when building elements as a shared library
- The problem does not occur in CMake Debug build type
- The problem does not occur when LTO is not enabled
- All of affected classes that have this problem (after trying multple commits) have multiple inheritance

Comment: LTO is generally non-functional for MinGW targets due to issues like this. I would save yourself the trouble and disable it. The version of you linker will also be relevant to figuring out what is going wrong here. What version of binutils are you using?

Comment: I reproduced this both with GCC 8.3.1 + GNU ld 2.30 and GCC 9.2.1 + GNU ld 2.33.1. Not sure where I would check the binutils version.

Comment: The `ld` version is the binutils version. So at least it still occurs with version 2.33.1. I would consider reporting a binutils bug. This would require some simple repro case though. You can probably throw away everything in your code except the symbols it's complaining about and use that.

Comment: Threw away all other classes, stripped the library to roughly 10-15 classes, does not reproduce. I guess optimization-related reproduction is going to be really hard to hit given error case considering inlining and other optimizations that behave differently on different code sizes. Got any other ideas?

Comment: Well, I guess a big repro is better than none. Perhaps the binutils folks have a better idea how to figure this out. Just don't hold your breath, MinGW isn't a high-activity development target.