# Which is the correct way to build a static library with link time code generation on Linux?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, lto

I'm wandering which is the right way to compile static library on Linux with GCC in such way that when link time optimizations (LTO) be applied to the executable the library to be consumable and possibly to be achieved optimal performance.

When library is compiled only with `-flto` the executable cannot be linked to it no matter whether it uses `-flto` or not. The error is:

> undefined reference to `hello'

where `hello` is function defined in the library.

According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236917/using-gccs-link-time-optimization-with-static-linked-libraries/39256013) Stack Overflow question one possible solution is the following:

```
set(CMAKE_AR gcc-ar)
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcs <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH true)
```

Then the library can be linked to the executable both with `-flto` and without `-flto` passed to the linker flags.

But according to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799452/what-is-the-difference-in-gcc-between-lto-and-fat-lto-objects) Stack Overflow question if we want static library to be compiled in such way to be usable with and without LTO than we have to use `-ffat-lto-objects`. If we add this flag to the library compilation flags again the library can be linked to executables both with `-flto` and without `-flto` passed to the linker flags.

My questions are:

1. What is the exact meaning of the first solution with `gcc-ar`?
2. What is the difference between different working variants when library is compiled with `-flto`.

   2.1 Executable without `-flto`.

   - Library is using only `gcc-ar`.
   - Library is using only `-ffat-lto-objects`.
   - Library is using both `gcc-ar` and `-ffat-lto-objects`

   2.2 Executable with `-flto` and the same 3 variants for the library.

Here is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with my test project which is modified version of the example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236917/using-gccs-link-time-optimization-with-static-linked-libraries/39256013) Stack Overflow question. I'm using GCC version `7.2.0`.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(lto)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -g -O3")

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(exe)
```

exe/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TARGET_NAME exe)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} src/main.c)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} lib)

option(EXE_LTO "Use link time optimizations for the executable." OFF)

if(${EXE_LTO})
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE "-flto")
endif()
```

exe/src/main.c

```
extern void hello();

int main()
{
  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(TARGET_NAME lib)

add_library(${TARGET_NAME} STATIC src/lib.c)

option(LIB_LTO "Use link time optimizations for the library." OFF)
option(LIB_FAT_LTO "Create fat LTO objects for library files." OFF)
option(LIB_USE_LTO_AR "Use another AR program for LTO objects." OFF)

if(${LIB_LTO})
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -flto)
endif()

if(${LIB_FAT_LTO})
  target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE -ffat-lto-objects)
endif()

if(${LIB_USE_LTO_AR})
  set(CMAKE_AR gcc-ar)
  set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> qcs <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
  set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH true)
endif()
```

lib/src/lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello()
{
  puts("Hello");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to add cmake tag to your question.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer CMake is not really relevant to the question but I only use it as build system. All of this can be done also without CMake.

Comment: "the executable cannot be linked to it".  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @n.m. Undefined references to called lib functions.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @n.m. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't add `--plugin /psth/to/lto-plugin.so*` to `ar` parameters, you will get undefined references at link time *and a warning at archive creation time*. Or at least that's what I'm getting. You probably need to add it here:

```
set(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> --plugin <LTO_PLUGIN_PATH> \
  qcs <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")
```

(`LINK_FLAGS` probably don't belong here, so I omitted them).

I don't know how to set LTO_PLUGIN_PATH automatically.

The plugin enables `ar` to create LTO-enabled archives. All other methods either don't work at all (non-fat objects in the archive) or don't actually result in link time optimisation (fat objects in the archive — in this case only the traditional object code is used, the LTO information is ignored).

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions which I asked. What is the meaning of `liblto_plugin` used by `ar` and what is the difference of this solution with using only `-ffat-lto-objects` which also works without `liblto_plugin`? See `My questions are:` part.

Comment: @bobeff the meaning of --pkugun flag is "use the plugin". It is required for building lto-enabled archives, as your warning message should have said.

Comment: But why the example works also only with `-ffat-lto-objects`? Maybe than always normal compiled code is used by linker instead of intermediate code no matter of `-flto` flag?

Comment: "All other methods either don't work at all (non-fat objects in the archive) or don't actually result in link time optimisation (fat objects in tge archive)." I think that this answers the question and I will accept it.

Comment: I think you can place a symlink to the plugin .so in `/usr/lib/bfd-plugins/` and `ar`, `nm` etc should pick it up (but I'm struggling with LTO at the moment myself)

Answer (score 2):

Instructions:

1. Compile your object files with options `-flto -fno-fat-lto-objects`. `-fno-fat-lto-objects` is not strictly necessary, however, it makes sure it either does lto or fails (instead of falling back to non-lto mode).
2. Create the static library with `ar rcsT --plugin <path-to-lto-plugin> ...` You need the full path to `liblto_plugin.so` here. Option `T` here creates a *thin* archive (does not copy `.o` files).
3. Link with `-flto` flag.

Example:

```
$ cat library.cc
namespace library {

int f(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}

}
$ cat test.cc
#include <iostream>

namespace library { int f(int); }

int main() {
    std::cout << library::f(0) << '\n';
}
$ g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++14 -O3 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -o library.o library.cc
$ ar rcsT --plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/liblto_plugin.so library.a library.o 
$ g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++14 -O3 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -o test.o test.cc
$ g++ -o test -flto -O3 test.o 
/tmp/ccY0l2jQ.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x37): undefined reference to `library::f(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++ -o test -flto test.o library.a
$ ./test
1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions which I asked. What is the meaning of `liblto_plugin` used by `ar` and what is the difference of this solution with using only `-ffat-lto-objects` which also works without `liblto_plugin`. See `My questions are:` part.